# JTattoo Look'n'feel в java приложении

Tags: java, jar

Я добавил библиотеку JTattoo в мой проект. Импортировал его в класс моей GUI SWING оболочки. Установил в качестве LaF'а для текущего приложения.

В IDE IDEA все компилируется и запускается отлично. Когда создал artefact (jar файл), тогда столкнулся с проблемой, что мой LaF отсутствует в jar'е. JVM при запуске выдает такую ошибку:

[image: ошибка при запуске jar файла]

Стектрейс:

[image]

Часть кода, где устанавливаю LaF:

```
import com.jtattoo.plaf.aluminium.AluminiumLookAndFeel;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() throws UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new AluminiumLookAndFeel());

...
}
```

Как включить LaF в jar моего приложения, чтобы он работал на всех компьютерах, где есть JVM?

Answer (score 1):

Изменил MANIFEST:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: MyClass
Class-Path: JTattoo-1.6.11.jar
```

Теперь все работает.